# CorePlot throws exceptions in iOS7 app / Xcode5

Tags: ios7, core-plot, xcode5

I have an iOS7 application that I am trying to integrate CorePlot 1.4 into (Dependent Project Install).

```
@property (nonatomic) CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView;
```

and

```
_hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
```

(`_hostingView` is subject to auto-layout.) If I then add a graph:

```
CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

I first get this exception:

```
-[CPTTextStyle attributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa392900
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTTextStyle attributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa392900'
5   myapp                     0x00074325 -[CPTAxis updateAxisLabelsAtLocations:inRange:useMajorAxisLabels:] + 1141
6   myapp                     0x00075662 -[CPTAxis relabel] + 1202
```

In desperation I have then fixed this in `updateAxisLabelsAtLocations:inRange:useMajorAxisLabels` by:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = nil;
BOOL hasAttributedFormatter  = FALSE;
```

and then get the next exception:

```
-[__NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9591e90
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9591e90'
5   myapp                     0x00081520 -[CPTTextLayer sizeThatFits] + 320
6   myapp                     0x0008163c -[CPTTextLayer sizeToFit] + 108
7   myapp                     0x00080559 -[CPTTextLayer initWithText:style:] + 313
8   myapp                     0x00074b87 -[CPTAxis updateAxisLabelsAtLocations:inRange:useMajorAxisLabels:] + 3159
9   myapp                     0x00075672 -[CPTAxis relabel] + 1202
```

I have then 'fixed' this by commenting out this line in `sizeThatFits`:

```
    else {
     //   textSize = [myText sizeWithTextStyle:self.textStyle];
    }
```

Next exception is then:

```
-[__NSCFString drawInRect:withTextStyle:inContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa162bd0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString drawInRect:withTextStyle:inContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa162bd0'
5   myapp                     0x00081dc8 -[CPTTextLayer renderAsVectorInContext:] + 1144
6   myapp                     0x00063f60 -[CPTLayer drawInContext:] + 112
```

which is fixed by commenting out below code in `renderAsVectorInContext`:

```
    else {
     //   [myText drawInRect:newBounds
     //        withTextStyle:self.textStyle
     //            inContext:context];
    }
```

Now finally no exceptions are thrown and the graph borders are shown. But if I then begin to add data/legend, etc. new exceptions are thrown :(

No text is shown on the axis etc. Of course this is because I have commented out the code. But any clue why these exceptions are thrown? I am desperate ;S

It seems like I have missed something fundamental in the integration. But my integration (CorePlot 1.3 though) worked fine in an iOS6 app on Xcode4 some time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the linker flags in your app project. Core Plot requires `-ObjC` and `-all_load`. See the Core Plot [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eric - great relief! Feel stupid now :) Any plans to refactor CorePlot to use ARC?

Comment: The 2.0 release (already in a branch) will drop GC support and use ARC. There's no timetable for the release yet.